# NetLogo: Adding and removing items from a list

Tags: list, netlogo

Every time an agent gets a new value for some action they're performing, I want them to add it to the end of a list. If the list has ten or more items on it, I want them to remove the first item on the list, so that the list has the ten most recent values an agent has seen, in order. How might I do that? (Edit: forgot to ask an actual question.)

I want to be able to apply mathematical operations to each item on the list, so I don't want a list of cons cell-like lists, unless there's some easy way to apply mathematical operations to each item in such a list that I don't know about.

Comment: Include some code you've written and describe what does not work.

Answer (score 9):

Let's build a simple example, where each turtle makes a slight right turn at a random angle at every tick, and stores the history of these angles in a list:

```
turtles-own [ history ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 3 [
    set history [] ; initialize history to an empty list
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    let angle random 5
    right angle
    ; add the angle of the most recent turn
    ; at the end of the list
    set history lput angle history
    if length history > 10 [
      ; remove the first item from the list
      set history but-first history
    ]
    forward 0.1
  ]
  tick
end
```

> I don't want a list of cons cell-like lists, unless there's some easy way to apply mathematical operations to each item in such a list that I don't know about.

I don't know what you mean by "a list of cons cell-like lists", but a simple list like the one we built here is by far the best thing you can use if you want to do math.

To apply an operation to each item, use [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map). And then you can use functions like [`sum`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sum) or [`mean`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#mean) to operate on the whole list. For example:

```
to do-math
  ask turtles [
    let doubled-history map [ a -> a * 2 ] history
    show history
    show doubled-history
    show mean doubled-history
  ]
end
```

(Note that this uses NetLogo 6.0.1 syntax.)

Let's see a demonstration:

```
observer> setup repeat 5 [ go ] do-math
(turtle 2): [4 3 2 1 2]
(turtle 2): [8 6 4 2 4]
(turtle 2): 4.8
(turtle 1): [4 0 1 1 4]
(turtle 1): [8 0 2 2 8]
(turtle 1): 4
(turtle 0): [2 0 4 1 0]
(turtle 0): [4 0 8 2 0]
(turtle 0): 2.8
```